# Powershell script write to one file simultaneously Out-File -FilePath -InputObject -Append

Tags: powershell

I made a powershell script that writes data to one text file.

Script is being executed with 3rd party software deploying program. Good thing is that it waits when computer is online and it executes a job, bad thing is when script is being executed on already 100+ online computers I got information from only 8 computers and 2 empty lines.

Most likely it happened because powershell script was running simultaneously on 100+ computers and that file was in use.

No way to use "wait for script being executed on first computer" in 3rd party software deployment program.

The problem is with line -

```
$srvpath = [path to text file]
$computer = "Name of computer"
$data = "Some data not more than ~30 characters"
Out-File -FilePath $srvpath -InputObject "$computer - $data" -Append
```

My current solution is to make temporary file for each computer separately and later launch 2nd script that will read those files write to one file (sort alphabetically) and delete temporary files.

But I would like to stick with one script so is it possible to check if data was written to the file or check if text file is already in use and then wait? Would be nice to avoid extra empty lines as well, but that's not a big issue.

Comment: I've never had much success with multiple computers appending to the same file. The strategy I typically use is to have each computer create its own separate output file on a central server share.  The filename is prefixed with the computer name to prevent duplicate filenames.  Once I'm satisifed all the computers have finished their run, I append all the data from the central share.

Comment: Another option would be to run the script code via `Start-Job` on the remote systems, and collect the results from the completed jobs (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171)).