# Parallel scripting with jobs using filter

Tags: c#, powershell, parallel-processing

I have written up a script that builds out hundreds of virtual machines in Hyper-V but at this time it creates one machines per host based on a CSV file that has a virtual machine per row.

```
CSV input looks kinda like this:
HOSTNAME,VMName,CPU,MEM,VHDPATH
Host1,test1,2,4,D:\server2008.vhd
Host1,test2,2,4,D:\server2k3.vhd
Host2,test3,2,4,D:\server2k3.vhd
Host2,test4,2,4,D:\server2k3.vhd
Host3,test5,2,4,D:\server2k3.vhd
Host3,test6,2,4,D:\server2k3.vhd
```

What I want to do is, if there are multiple VMs on same host (such as above) I want to just build one VM on there at a time but in parallel, I want to build out VMs on other hosts. The idea is that each host will have 1 VM being created and there will be multiple creations happening in parallel on different hosts. As a VM completes, it moves down the list for that host and builds next. In theory, there should be 3 VMs being created at the same time, 1 per host.

I have tried setting up jobs but can't get it right, please advise! Thank you in advance

*UPDATE*

How would I take the input file, create a list of machines sepearted into arrays based on host. Then do this job per host, per array?

Comment: Show us what you've got.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171) for an example of a job queue with size limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on PowerShell V3 use Workflow.

```
workflow Provision-VM {
    param([psobject[]]$HostInfo)

    foreach -parallel ($host in $HostInfo) {
        foreach ($vmInfo in $host.VM) {
            Invoke-Command -cn $host.Name -File path-to-script.ps1 -Arg $vmInfo
        }
    }
}
```

I would consolidate the VM info for each host into a single custom object per host and pass that into the workflow.  In general I stay away from doing fine-grained script inside the workflow especially when it can be worked out before invoking the workflow.

A HostInfo object would look like this:

```
$hostInfo += [pscustomobject]@{Name='Host1';VM=@([pscustomobject]@{Name='test1';CPU=2;MEM=4;VHDPATH='c:\...'},[pscustomobject]@{... next VM ...})}
```