# How to add an element back into an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement

First off, I am new to Powershell, so please excuse any poor coding here.

I'm trying to write a script that queues commands. We have a piece of equipment that can only handle 32 commands at one time. What I want to do is build a command file that has many more than 32 commands and then it automatically queues any command after 32 until another free slot opens up. Everything seems to be working except when I go into my 'else' statement. I attempt to add the current $_ back into the array so it doesn't get lost and gets reprocessed, but this does not seem to be working.

I build my array from a text file:
`$commands = @(Get-Content C:\scripts\temp\commands.txt)`

When I try to add the current $_ value back into the array during the 'else' pause statement, it never adds back in, so that one particular command never enters back into the array. So if my script has to pause 15 times, 15 commands will never get ran as they just get processed by the 'else' statement and get thrown out of my 'if/else' loop.

Here's my if/else loop:

```
$commands | ForEach-Object {
If (Test-Path C:\scripts\temp\active_migrations.txt){
Remove-Item C:\scripts\temp\active_migrations.txt
}
CMD.EXE /C "ssh $user@$cluster -pw $PlainPassword lsmigrate" > C:\scripts\temp\active_migrations.txt
$count = Get-Content C:\scripts\temp\active_migrations.txt
$number_of_migrations = $count.Length / 6
IF ($number_of_migrations -lt 32)
{
Write-Host "Migrations are currently at $number_of_migrations. Proceeding with next vdisk migration."
Write-Host "Issuing command $_"
Write-Host "There are still $migrations_left migrations to execute of $total_migrations total."
Write-Host ""
CMD.EXE /C "ssh $user@$cluster -pw $PlainPassword $_"
SLEEP 2
$migrations_left--
           }
ELSE
{
Write-Host "Migrations are currently at $number_of_migrations. Sleeping for 1 minute"
$commands = @($commands + $_)
Write-Host "There are still $migrations_left migrations to execute of $total_migrations total."
SLEEP 60
           }}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: where do you actually remove the command from the array? just because you access a value doesn´t mean it gets deleted

Comment: I don't explicitly remove it. Maybe I worded my question a bit strange. Basically, if there are 300 values in the array, I need to make sure all 300 values successfully run 'CMD.EXE /C "ssh $user@$cluster -pw $PlainPassword $_"' whether the script has to pause or not. Let's just say the value is currently "hello world". Let's also say that there are currently 32 commands executing, so the script drops to the else loop. What I need to happen is that once the executing commands becomes less than 32, I still need "hello world" to be executed. Does that help? Sorry...this is a tough one to explain

Comment: have you checked the array if the values are added? probably it just doesnt loop through them because the loop has already been started. Maybe you can just create a second array to add the commands and then cycle through that after your first loop finished?

Comment: I have not checked. But I really like the idea of making another array and adding $_ to that during the else loop. I'll try that and let you know. Thank you Paul.

Comment: good luck :) if that doesnt work you could also try to do a while-loop in your else. Something like while($number_of_migrations -gt 32){} and then execute the command after the loop. But this will halt your script and probably use more cpu power (not sure about that though)

Comment: I suggest you re-evaluate your approach. Basically you're queueing jobs here, so you should implement this with an actual [job queue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Paul. I ended up dumping things during the else statement to a temp array and it works! Appreciate the assistance.

```
function commands_temp
{
if (Test-Path C:\scripts\temp\commands_temp.txt) 
{
$commands=@()
$commands=@(Get-Content C:\scripts\temp\commands_temp.txt)
Remove-Item C:\scripts\temp\commands_temp.txt
Proceed
}
Else
{
Write-Host "All migrations are either complete or successfully executed. Check the GUI or run lsmigrate CLI command for full status."
```