# Run powershell commands in parallel

Tags: powershell

How can I run a PowerShell script in parallel on multiple computers?

```
 $TempFolder = "C:\DOWNLOADED_APPLICATIONS"
            if(!(test-path $TempFolder))
            {New-Item -path $TempFolder -type directory}

    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Downloading .NET framework v4.0 installation package" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
            $src = "\\onesoul\tools\DOTNET45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe"
            $dest = "$TempFolder" + "\" + "dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe"
            $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
            $wc.DownloadFile($src, $dest)
            $args = " /q /norestart"
        Write-Host "Installing .NET framework v4.0" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
        Start-Process -FilePath $dest -ArgumentList $args -Wait
        Write-Output "Dot net 4.5 installed"
```

This script works fine if I run it remotely on one computer at a time. How do I make it run in parallel?

Comment: You could use [jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171).

Comment: Depending on your environment, you might be better off to just do the download once, then copy that to the other machines and kick off the install on each one using invoke-command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run scripts on multiple remote computers you use PowerShell remoting. This requires that every computer you connect to has to have PowerShell remoting enabled which you do with the command:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Then from your PC, running an elevated console, use the Invoke-Command to run a script against multiple computers e.g.:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer server1,server2,server3 -Auth CredSSP `
    -FilePath c:\script.ps1 -ArgumentList scriptParameter1, scriptParameter2
```

I suggest you use the `-Auth CredSSP` to avoid a second hop issue with your credentials since you're accessing a network share from the remote computer.  Also the FilePath parameter will take the path to a local script and copy its contents across the wire to each remote computer.  That script should not rely on other scripts unless they exist on all the remote computers.  Finally, if you use your credentials, you should admin privs on all the remote computers. If you don't, use the -Credential parameter to provides credentials for an account that does.