# ForEach-Object actions Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, vmware

I am trying to specify a structured order of commands and I am looking for an easier way than I currently have.  I have an ordered reboot of a series of servers.  The servers are in tiers, so the tiers must be shut down in a particular order, then brought back up in the reverse order.  Also time is a concern as there are a lot of servers and I don't want a ton of down time.

What I have is this...

```
$Servers | Where-Object {$_.Tier -match "App"} | ForEach-Object {
    Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $_.Name -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
    }
$Servers | Where-Object {$_.Tier -match "App"} | ForEach-Object {
    while(((Get-VM $_.Name).PowerState -ne "PoweredOff") -and ($sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $timeout)) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
if ((Get-VM $_.Name).PowerState -ne "PoweredOff") {
    Stop-VM -VM $_.Name -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
    }
}
```

I then just repeat this code over and over for all of the tiers.  Is there an easier way to shut the servers down FIRS, then go into my verify loop (using a pipe maybe).  Also, is there a way I can make a "command loop" so I don't have to have such a long an unmanageable script?

Comment: Create a job (scriptblock) that executes the activities above (Shutdown -> Verify -> Stop). These should execute in parallel. Group the jobs into tiers, which are executed in sequence. Create a list for each tier to place finished jobs in order. Finally, go through the list in reverse to bring up the servers.

Comment: What @MFT said. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you should use [Workflows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/22/the-basics-of-windows-powershell-workflow-when-to-use-it-and-why.aspx)