# Simultaneous PowerShell script execution

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have written the following script for SQL patching:

```
    cls
$computers =  Get-Content D:\Abhi\Server.txt
foreach ($line in $computers)
{
    psexec \\$line -s -u Adminuser -p AdminPassword msiexec /i D:\SQL_PATCH\rsSharePoint.msi SKIPCA=1 /qb
}
```

My doubt here is to parallelize this script execution on all the servers mentioned in the text file. Meaning, as soon I start the execution of the script, this should initiate the patching activity on the servers simultaneously and also to track the progess on all the servers, as this script is doing now only for one server.
Kindly help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PowerShell to run virus scan on multiple servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192550/use-powershell-to-run-virus-scan-on-multiple-servers)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I have made my code more simpler. The thing that I don't understand from the link in your comments is how can I pass server names to this `psexec \\$line -s -u Adminuser -p AdminPassword msiexec /i D:\SQL_PATCH\rsSharePoint.msi SKIPCA=1 /qb`?? Kindly clarify

Comment: Define the code you want to execute as a scriptblock. Start the scriptblock as a job and pass `$line` as the argument to the scripblock. The sample code from my answer to the other question uses a queue for managing the hostnames, so that at most `$maxSlots` jobs are running at the same time. Also, please avoid making radical changes to your questions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Apologies for last minute changes to the code. Can you please provide a sample as to what edit you are referring w.r.t above code. I'm still not getting what to edit. As you can see I want `psexec` to be run as Job. Please help

Comment: Define the `psexec` statement as a scripbblock (`$job = { ... }`). Start jobs passing the hostnames into the scriptblock as arguments (`foreach ($line in $computers) { Start-Job -ScriptBlock $job -ArgumentList $line }`). If you want your scriptblock to have named parameters you need to add a `Param()` statement to it, otherwise the arguments will be available inside the scriptblock via the `$args` collection. Please read up on [jobs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847783.aspx) and [parameter handling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Thanks for your comment. My doubt here is that the `psexec` already has `$line` arugument. I don't think providing that again in the `foreach` loop is required. please comment

Comment: `$line` from the loop is not available inside the scriptblock. Please re-read my previous comment.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I'm trying this code:
`$computers = gc 'D:\Abhi\Server.txt'

$job = {psexec -s -u Adminuser -p AdminPassword msiexec /i D:\SQL_PATCH\rsSharePoint.msi SKIPCA=1 /qb}
foreach ($line in $computers)
{
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $job -ArgumentList $line
}`
But nothing is getting installed on the remote server. Please look into this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80054/discussion-between-lilly123-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ansgar Wiechers.
This piece of code did it. It helps in executing the **.exe** simultaneously on all the servers as well as track their status:

```
cls
$servers = Get-Content 'D:\Abhi\Server.txt'

$servers | ForEach-Object {$comp = $_

           Start-Job -ScriptBlock {psexec \\$input -s -u Adminuser -p AdminPassword C:\SQL_PATCH\SQLServer2008R2SP3-KB2979597-x64-ENU.exe /quiet /action=patch /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms} -InputObject $comp}


While (Get-Job -State Running) 
{
    Get-Job | Receive-Job
    #Start-Sleep 2 
    #Write-Host "Waiting for update removal to finish ..."
}  

Remove-Job *
```