# Run constant number of scripts in parallel with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a large number of scripts. Each script does not load the server too much and can be run in parallel with other script. Typically 3 scripts can run at once.

Currently I run it grouped by 3 scripts

```
$p1 = Start-Process...
$p2 = Start-Process...
$p3 = Start-Process...
// wait for completion
Wait-Process -InputObject $p1,$p2,$p3
```

However it is often that script 1 needs much more time than script 2 and 3 and the whole process is waiting only for script 1 to complete.

I would like to keep running 3 scripts constantly.
In my example, if script 3 complete quickly, then script 4 runs without waiting for 1 and 2.

How to do that with Powershell ?

Comment: Use a [job queue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171).

Comment: Ansgar, thank you for sharing your code!