# Need to Multithread this script and log the results of each

Tags: multithreading, powershell

Need to multithread this script and log the results of each run.  This is to gather the information on the SEP agent installed.  The code will be run to check a couple thousand computers.  I have attempted to use a separate script to invoke multithreading but I am not getting anything posted to the log file.  When I run this script alone, it works perfectly.

```
function Get-SEPVersion {
  # Connect to Registry
  try {
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$Server)

    # Create object to enable access to the months of the year
    DateTimeFormat = New-Object System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo

    # Check OS Architecture
    $is64bitSystem = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $Server).OSArchitecture

    if ($is64bitSystem -eq "64-bit") {
      # Set Registry keys to query
      $SMCKey = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\SMC"
      $AVKey = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\AV"
      $SylinkKey = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\SMC\\SYLINK\\SyLink"
    }
    if ($is64bitSystem -eq $true) {
      # Set Registry keys to query
      $SMCKey = "SOFTWARE\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\SMC"
      $AVKey = "SOFTWARE\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\AV"
      $SylinkKey = "SOFTWARE\\Symantec\\Symantec Endpoint Protection\\SMC\\SYLINK\\SyLink"
    }

    # Obtain Product Version value
    $SMCRegKey = $reg.opensubkey($SMCKey)
    $SEPVersion = $SMCRegKey.GetValue('ProductVersion')

    # Obtain Pattern File Date Value
    $AVRegKey = $reg.opensubkey($AVKey)
    $AVPatternFileDate = $AVRegKey.GetValue('PatternFileDate')

    # Obtain Pattern File Revision Value
    $AVRevisionKey = $AVRegKey.GetValue('PatternFileRevision')

    # Convert PatternFileDate to readable date
    $AVYearFileDate = [string]($AVPatternFileDate[0] + 1970)
    $AVMonthFileDate = $DateTimeFormat.MonthNames[$AVPatternFileDate[1]]
    $AVDayFileDate = [string]$AVPatternFileDate[2]
    $AVFileVersionDate = $AVDayFileDate + " " + $AVMonthFileDate + " " + $AVYearFileDate

    # Obtain Sylink Group value
    $SylinkRegKey = $reg.opensubkey($SylinkKey)
    $SylinkGroup = $SylinkRegKey.GetValue('CurrentGroup')

    $Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty
    $hostdns = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($Server)
               $OS = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Server -ErrorAction Stop -Credential $Credential
               $BootTime = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LastBootUpTime)
               $Uptime = $OS.ConvertToDateTime($OS.LocalDateTime) - $boottime
    $MYObject = "" | Select-Object ComputerName,SEPProductVersion,SEPDefinitionDate,SylinkGroup,BootTime,UpTime
    $MYObject.ComputerName = $Server
    $MYObject.SEPProductVersion = $SEPVersion
    $MYObject.SEPDefinitionDate = "$AVFileVersionDate, Revision $AVRevisionKey"
    $MYObject.SylinkGroup = $SylinkGroup
    $MYObject.UpTime = $UpTime
    LogWrite "$Server, $SEPVersion, $AVFileVersionDate, Revision $AVRevisionKey, $SylinkGroup, $Boottime, $UpTime"
    $MYObject
  } catch {
    LogWrite  "$Server, - Manual Check Required"
    Write-Host "$Server - Manual Check Required"
  }
}

# Write Headers to the log file
function StartLog {
  Param ([string]$logstring)
  $Logfile = "C:\Temp\PS Scripts\Logs\SEP Status.log"
  $Logstring = "Computer, SEP Version, Def Date, Sylink Group, BootTime, Uptime"
  Add-Content $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

# Write results to a log file
function LogWrite {
  Param ([string]$logstring)
  $Logfile = "C:\Temp\PS Scripts\Logs\SEP Status.log"
  Add-Content $Logfile -Value $logstring
}

# Get list of Computers to process
function Get-FileName {
  [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")

  $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OpenFileDialog.filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*" # Set the file types visible to dialog

  # Alternate filters include:
  # "CSV files (*.csv) | *.csv"

  $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\test\"

  $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
  $OpenFileDialog.FileName
}

# Main Script

StartLog
$filename = Get-FileName
$filecontents = Get-Content $filename
foreach ($Computername in $filecontents) {
  # Determine if the OS running this script is 32-bit
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Get-SEPVersion
  } else {
    Write-Warning "$Server Offline or not responding to pings"
    LogWrite  "$Server, - is OFFLINE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [background jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171) to run the code in parallel.

Comment: Ok, I put all my code into a scriptblock called $sb and modified the code from  the background jobs link, but it does not seem to pass the computer name on to the script block.

Comment: $filename = Get-FileName
    $Computers = Get-Content $filename
    
    
    
    $maxSlots = 10
    
    
    $job = {
      Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $sb } -Computer $ARGV[0] -ThrottleLimit 10 #-Authentication domain/admin
    }
    
    $queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.Queue))
    $Computers | % { $queue.Enqueue($_) }

Comment: `$sb` -> `$using:sb`