# Parallel retrieval of user sessions from multiple Windows servers in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Assume I have an array of Windows hostnames:

```
$server_hostnames = @("server1","server2")
```

For each server I need to find if there are any sessions for a specific user, and then ideally capture all the sessions in a new array.

```
$results = @()
$account = "JohnDoe"
foreach ($s in $server_hostnames) {
    $r = (qwinsta /server:$($s) 2> $null | out-string -stream | sls $account)
    $results += $r
}
```

In this example I have 2 servers but in production I would run it against 2-3000 servers, so parallel execution is extremely important.

I have made several attempts at rewriting the code using jobs, workflows, or `Split-Pipeline`, but with little success.
Usually, filtering with `sls` (`Select-String`) doesn't work, not even with `findstr`.

`Split-Pipeline` example:

```
PS C:\SplitPipeline> $server_hostnames | Split-Pipeline {process{ $_; qwinsta /server:$($_) | out-string -stream | sls $account }}
Split-Pipeline : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null.
At line:1 char:21
+ $server_hostnames | Split-Pipeline {process{ $_; qwinsta /server:$($_) | out-str ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Pipeline], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,SplitPipeline.SplitPipelineCommand
```

Comment: Looks like $account has an empty value. Where do you assign it from ?

Comment: It is not null, in my example you can see that $account = "JohnDoe"

Comment: Can you see what do you get when you execute this: $server_hostnames | Split-Pipeline {process{ $_; qwinsta /server:$($_) | out-string -stream }}

Comment: It works, I get the expected results (all the sessions). It seems that the error arises when I add Select-String (sls), but I don't understand why or how to get around it..

Comment: It's weird. If you try executing 'sls $notavalidvariable' you will exactly get the error 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is null'. Since $notavalidvariable is Null' (Note that if u try sls "" you will get a different error)  Can you try your statement by hardcoding "JohnDoe" instead of using $account ?

Comment: If I hardcode the value it works; does this mean I can't access variables outside of its internal scope? If so, how could I get around this?

Comment: Update your question with your complete script !! Lets work it out !

Comment: The error you're getting from your `Split-Pipeline` example is because the variable `$account` is defined *outside* the scriptblock, but not *inside* it. To be able to use `$account` (or other variables from the outside scope) in the scriptblock you must pass them as arguments or use the `using:` scope modifier.

Comment: Ansgar thanks for the tip, I'll see if I can fix it on my own and post it here!

@PrageethSaravanan I had already posted my complete script with Split-Pipeline... I also had a version using jobs and another with workflows but I scrapped those.

Answer (score 0):

Using jobs you could do something like this:

```
$servers = 'server1', 'server2'
$account = 'JohnDoe'
$results = @()

$sb = {
  Param($server, $name)
  & qwinsta /server:$server |
    Select-String $name -SimpleMatch |
    Select-Object -Expand Line
}

$servers | ForEach-Object {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $_, $account | Out-Null
}

$results += while (Get-Job -State Running) {
  Get-Job -State Complete | ForEach-Object {
    Receive-Job -Job $_
    Remove-Job -Job $_
  }
}

$results += Get-Job -State Complete | ForEach-Object {
  Receive-Job -Job $_
  Remove-Job -Job $_
}
```

However, since you want to run `qwinsta` against several thousand servers you'll probably want to use a [job queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171) rather than running all jobs at the same time, otherwise the massive number of jobs might exhaust your local computer's resources.

Comment: Thanks again Ansgar, this is beautiful code; I've tested this version as well and as you predicted it exhausts all resources; I will try to rewrite it with a queue!

Comment: I've been a bit busy these past few days, but I successfully rewrote the script to use a queue (I've added it to the original question). The physical resources of the local machine remain a bottleneck, I have settled with a maximum # of concurrent jobs of 75.
There's just one more thing I need taking care of... each job result (each line) should also contain the name of the server, otherwise the output isn't entirely useful..

Comment: Please do not edit answers into your question. You're free to post an answer of your own. As for including the hostname in the output, you could for instance echo `$server` or `$env:COMPUTERNAME` in the job scriptblock.

Comment: Thanks, I think you misunderstood me a bit: I don't need to include the hostname of the local machine where the script is running, what I want is for each found session to include the name of the server where it originates.

Comment: Ah, yes, `$env:COMPUTERNAME` wouldn't work in this scenario. `$server` would, though.