# restart computer on all hosts at the same time

Tags: powershell

I have an idea about restarting all of host/VMs in my inventory. 
I created some short script which restarting one by one of hosts.
But it's take to long time. How can i do that all hosts to be restarted at the same time?

My code:

```
foreach ($host in $hosts) {
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $host -Wait
    Write-Host "$host restarted "
}
```

Comment: Unless you have a negligible number of hosts you most definitely do NOT want to restart all computers (virtual or physical) at the same time. It'd put a huge strain on the host operating system or power supply. I'd say the best approach is to restart the systems in batches via a [job queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171).

Answer (score 2):

`Restart-Computer` will accept multiple entries for `ComputerName` so you can perform the restart on more than one host at a time.

Using this you can initiate the restart in batches, say three at a time, this will significantly decrease the time it takes without adding too much load on the VM Cluster/Host.

```
$hosts = @("server01","server02","server03","server04","server05","server06","server07","server08","server09","server10")

[int]$batches = 3 #number of computers to restart in each 'batch'
[int]$skip = 0

do {
    $selected_hosts = $hosts | Select-Object -First $batches -Skip $skip

    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $selected_hosts -Wait -WhatIf
    Write-Host "$selected_hosts restarted"

    $skip = $skip + $batches
}
while ($selected_hosts)
```

Note: Remove `-WhatIf` when you're ready to run the script live, with this in place `Restart-Computer` will just write to Console informing you what it would do and not actually performing the restart.

Answer (score 0):

is it a good idea ??  - Restart-Computer -asJob 
Or maybe are better solutions ??

```
$j = Restart-Computer -ComputerName "Server01", "Server02" -AsJob
PS C:\> $Results = $j | Receive-Job
PS C:\> $Results
```

Comment: Why as job is a better solution? Is he looking for a parallel solution ?

Comment: @RanadipDutta: well, if you read their question, then it definitely sounds like it.

Comment: my bad. you are right. Although I prefer to use start-process for all of the servers .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `WMI` to reboot the servers. I found one such method on `social.technet.microsoft` Forum.

```
$server = get-content c:\Servers.txt

(gwmi -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server).Win32Shutdown(6)
If ($?) {
Write-Host "$server successfully rebooted"
}Else{
Write-Host "Could not reboot $server"
}
```

You can find other methods also like using a batch file. Check out [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b72ea9de-80f3-42fd-936a-a4315ed86abd/rebooting-multiple-servers-as-same-time-via-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) link.