# What is the most efficient way on getting a list of files utilizing get-childitem

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have created a list of PowerShell commands for getting over 500,000 rows of directories. The goal is to get a list of the files in each of the directories specified in the PowerShell command. My syntax works perfectly if I run a small batch, but there are definitely performance issues when running them in a bulk manner. One thing I noticed is that if I run all these 500,000 rows together, I get extremely high usage (about 12GB and using 97% of memory) and it takes a while for me to even begin to generate a CSV file. Please see my code listed below on what I am using

I was thinking I can get a list of the directories I need to use into a CSV. And researching around here, I can use a CSV as a variable and a `foreach`. But I am stumped on putting all that together.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\MYIP\ARCHIVE\ArchiveVolumes\UniqueID\ -Exclude *.wav*,*.md5*,*.abc, -Recurse |
    Select-Object FullName |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Myfield -Value 123456 -PassThru |
    Export-Csv -Append -Path C:\mypath\fileslist.csv -Encoding ascii -NoType
```

I'm hoping that I can better utilize what I am running here as I am still learning powershell. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know about the most efficient way, but wrapping your commandline in arbitrary places (and thus breaking it) has to be the least efficient way.

Comment: Just to be clear, the commands run fine. I'm guessing where you saw the codeblock being broke off is what you are referring to. I updated it in my question.

Comment: Try copy/pasting that code block into your PowerShell console. See the errors? *That* is what I was referring to. Please avoid adding new bugs to your code when posting a question.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I misunderstood how to insert the code. I was using an indent of 4 when I copied and pasted onto here. Now that I just indented the first line, it should be good now.

Comment: Yeah. I just reformatted it for better readability while keeping it intact. It's usually safe to wrap PowerShell statements after pipes, commas or operators. With that said, it's not quite clear to me what you mean by "500,000 rows of directories". Do you mean you have half a million individual paths to traverse? And are all of them UNC paths? On the same system or different ones?

Comment: Two things worth noting are that [calculated properties](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx) usually are preferable to `Add-Member` when you want to add properties in a pipeline, and appending to a file tends to be slower than writing a file in one go.

Comment: Yes that is correct. There is a list of half a million directories that I have. And within those directories, I am getting a recursive file list (with some exclusions). So the end result is getting a csv list of all the individual files. Obviously I know that no matter what, this will take a while. However, I believe I could be more efficient than simply running 500,000 lines in a single .ps1 script.

Comment: Well, `Get-ChildItem` accepts multiple directories (`Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo', 'C:\bar', 'D:\baz'`), but I doubt that you can fit in half a million that way. You can pass a list of directories like this (reading them from a file): `Get-Content 'dirlist.txt' | Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.wav*,*.md5*,*.abc, -Recurse | ...`, but processing half a million directories (recursively no less) is going to take time. You might be able to trade some time for memory consumption by using a [job queue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171), but that will take some fine tuning.

Comment: Please note that file names allow almost any Unicode character. So, a CSV file with Unicode's UTF-8 character encoding is more appropriate. Hopefully, you can use it in your processing.