# Script Launching Scripts - Limiting the number of concurrent scripts

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to launch many concurrent PowerShell scripts. The following logic functions well, until the Windows session locks or disconnects. Once that occurs, the script mercilessly launches each script regardless of the process count.

```cs
foreach ($Script in $Scripts) {
    if ((Get-Process powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count -lt 10) {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-File `"$Script`""
        Start-Sleep -s 5
    } else {
        while ((Get-Process powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count -lt 10) {
            Start-Sleep -s 30
        }
        Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-File `"$Script`""
        Start-Sleep -s 5
    }
}
```

Comment: have you taken a look at PoSh jobs yet? [*grin*] try reading the result of this `Get-Help about_Jobs`.

Comment: Thanks Lee! That's a much better way to handle things

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to help ... and good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18193195/1630171).

Answer (score -1):

I have use below simple powershell code to run the scripts from the folder. you can modified it

```
################################################
### Auto-load scripts on PowerShell startup ###
# directory where my scripts are stored
################################################

$psdir="C:\work\JumpStart\Autoload"  

Write-Host "Custom PowerShell Environment Start Loading" 
Write-Host " " 

# load all 'autoload' scripts
Get-ChildItem "${psdir}\*.ps1" | %{.$_}  
Get-ChildItem "${psdir}\*.ps1" | %{Write-host $_}  

Write-Host " " 
Write-Host "Custom PowerShell Environment Loaded" 

################################################
### Auto-load scripts on PowerShell startup ###
################################################
```

Comment: The question is about how to limit script concurrency, not how to launch them.